# Remove old directories according to directory's name?

Tags: bash, files, find, timestamps

In my bash script I create a directory each month for backups as follows:

```
DAY=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
MONTH=$(date -d "$D" '+%m')
YEAR=$(date -d "$D" '+%Y')

mkdir -p /var/app/backup/$DAY$MONTH$YEAR
```

For example I get:

```
 01012000
 01022000
 01032000
 .
 .
 01012014
 01022014
 01032014
 01042014
 .
 .
```

After years we want to remove the directories that are older than half of a year. For example - the directories from `01012000` until `01062000` should be removed at 1/1/2015.

What is the best approach (from bash script) in order to remove the directories that are older than half a year, regarding that we have the date in the directory's name?

Comment: do you mean `01012014` and `01062014` everything before `01062014`? Or every beginning half year as far as it goes back?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the filename into something that can be compared directly (such as the Unix timestamp (number of seconds since the epoch), or to `YYYYMMDD`, which would be lexicographically sortable), and then check if it's older than six months.

For example, a script like (say, at `/path/to/compare.sh`):

```
#! /bin/bash

LAST=$(date -d '6 months ago' +%s)

for FILE
do
    NAME=$(basename $FILE)
    DATE=$(perl -pe 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/$3$2$1/' <<<$NAME)
    if (( $(date -d "$DATE" '+%s') < $LAST ))
    then
        rm -r $FILE
    fi
done
```

And do:

```
/path/to/compare.sh /var/app/backup/*
```

Here I am converting to the number of seconds. I had to rearrange `DDMMYYY` to `YYYYMMDD`, since my `date` didn't accept the former as a valid date. The conversion to seconds is redundant because of that, but I am not sure why `date` is rejecting the former (perhaps a locale issue?).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to focus on just the removal part of your question. If you have the list of filenames like this:

```
$ cat data.txt
01012000
01022000
01032000
01012014
01022014
01032014
01042014
```

And you know that the cut off date for 6 months, is say "01022014". You can use `sort` & `sed` to determine which files need to be deleted, like so:

This will reverse sort the files:

```
$ sort -r data.txt 
01042014
01032014
01032000
01022014
01022000
01012014
01012000
```

This will drop off any of the newer files, leading up to our cut off date, "01022014".

```
$ sort -r data.txt | sed '1,/01032000/d'
01022014
01022000
01012014
01012000
```

**NOTE:** `sed '1,/PATTERN/d'` deletes (i.e. `d`) all the lines occurring from the first line (i.e. `1,`) until our PATTERN is encountered.

Finally, the list can then be sent to `xargs` for deletion:

```
$ sort -r data.txt | sed '1,/01032000/d' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ranged brace expansion:

Remove every half year:

```
echo /path/to/directories/01{01..06}{2000..2014}
```

OR remove everything except the last half year:

```
echo /path/to/directories/01{01..12}{2000..2013}
echo /path/to/directories/01{01..06}2014
```

Replace `echo` with `rm -r` and update the path.

Comment: yes but it should be automatic way ( as part of my bash script )

Comment: What do you mean by automatic? This will remove each directory as you originally asked it. I am a little confused.